# Cloud9 DB to mLab DB "Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide, mlab

I've looked at the similar questions but all are running local mongodb instances and the solutions are over my head.

I'm a newbie trying to port my database info from my Cloud 9 mongodb installation to an mLab database.  I'm using the exact pre-loaded string that mLab provides you, and getting "Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers"

```
mongoimport -h ds113892.mlab.com:13692 -d yelpcamp -c campgrounds -u <myusername> -p <mypassword> --file ~/workspace/YelpCamp/FinalDeployed/campexport.json
```

I can connect to the server with a mongo shell, but above command doesn't find a server.  I've tried it with and without mongod running in the background.  Super confused!  Would appreciate any help.

Comment: having the same error with `mongoexport`

Comment: I'm facing the same error with mongorestore. I'm trying to restore a collection to my MLAB database. While I can connect from the mongoshell, mongorestore keeps returning the error